# Program which copies one string to another using pointers produces no output

Tags: c, string, pointers, puts

I wrote following piece of code which copies from one string to another using pointers.

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int main() { 

    char strA[80] = "A string to be used for demonstration purposes"; 
    char strB[80]; 
    char *ptrA; 
    char *ptrB; 
    ptrA = strA; 
    ptrB = strB;
    puts(ptrA);
    while(*ptrA != '\0') { 
        *ptrB++ = *ptrA++;
    }
    *ptrB = '\0'; 
    puts(ptrB); // prints a new line. 
    return 0;

}
```

Why does `puts(ptrB)` print nothing but just a newline ? However `puts(ptrA)` prints the value of `strA`.

Comment: Where does `ptrB` point to after the loop? To a NUL-terminator! So nothing gets printed. The newline is added by `puts`.

Comment: Isn't is necessary to put a nul terminator character at the end of the char array? Am I missing anything here ? How to print the value of strB using ptrB ?

Comment: Yes it is.  But move `puts(ptrA)` *after* your `while` loop.

Comment: Yes. But you've incremented `ptrB` from the loop. After the loop, you assign the NUL-terminator. Now `ptrB` (and `ptrA`) points to the `\0` at the end of the string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After the loop, the two pointers `ptrA` and `ptrB` are now pointing to end of the string. Printing them is printing an empty string. The new line is added by `puts()`.

The reason `ptrA` prints the original string is because `puts(ptrA);` is called before the loop.

---

To print the original string, either use `puts(strB)`, or, if you like, let `ptrB` points back:

```
*ptrB = '\0'
ptrB = strB;  //add this
puts(ptrB);
```

Comment: So if I am writing my version strcpy, I would have to write the statement in the end  ptrB = strB to make it work. Is it the write way to do it ?

Comment: @user1534214 You mean the return value? A better way is to use another pointer to iterate the string, and return the original unmodified first argument.

Comment: Yes that is what I meant. Your comment made it clear. Thank You!

Comment: Or just `puts(strB)`?